# Heroku 'no such app' with no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having the hardest time trying to deploy a rails app to Heroku.

I push the app to it and receive no errors, but when I try to access it, I receive a 'no such app' message and I can't find out why.

I've followed this steps:

1) Cloned the git repo (https://github.com/mquan/lavish) in my local machine.

2) Changed the gemfile adding a newer version of the jquery-rails (as I was receiving an error) and added the 'thin' gem as stated at heroku documentation.

3) Installed it locally and it worked (in fact, it works if I run server rails, but not if I run server rails -e production).

4) Pushed it to heroku with no errors. (I tryed to precompile the assets too to see if I had any change).

5) When I visit the page (heroku open) I receive the 'No such app' message.

As I'm absolutely new to heroku and rails, I'm just clueless about what is happening.

Thanks a ton!

**Edit**

The log looks like this:

```
2012-11-14T06:36:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down

2012-11-14T06:36:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 59071`

2012-11-14T06:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach

2012-11-14T06:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server

2012-11-14T06:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin

2012-11-14T06:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.0 application starting in production on http:// 0.0.0.0:59071

2012-11-14T06:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)

2012-11-14T06:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024

2012-11-14T06:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:59071, CTRL+C to stop

2012-11-14T06:36:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM

2012-11-14T06:36:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting

2012-11-14T06:36:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0

2012-11-14T20:00:11+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started

2012-11-14T20:01:58+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished

2012-11-14T20:03:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling

2012-11-14T20:03:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting

2012-11-14T20:03:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

2012-11-14T20:03:37+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=blooming-castle-2034.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=13ms service=909ms status=301 bytes=14
```

Comment: Looks like the app is redirecting to the app url but with the "www" prefix. Do you have anything set to do this redirection?

Comment: Not that I know... Besides, this doesn't happen locally...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the code for [Lavish](https://github.com/mquan/lavish), it looks like there is an initializer file that is loaded on Rails boot that redirects all non-www domain requests to www. Heroku wont work with the www prefix before your Heroku app url.

[Here is a link to the file that should be removed](https://github.com/mquan/lavish/blob/master/config/initializers/use_www.rb)

As a disclaimer, I'm not sure if this will have adverse effects on the Lavish application, since I've never dealt with it before.